# Uso de bucle For para calcular notas

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que a través de Scanner meto notas y calculo su porcentaje ponderado, para finalmente sumar las notas ponderadas en una nota final. Mi problema es qué no sé como guardar esos datos que meto con Scanner para luego hacer los cálculos. Así debería quedar:

```
UNIDADES: 

Introduce el número de unidades: 3
UD 1:
Introduce el peso de la UD (0-100): 20
Introduce la puntuación obtenida (0-100):70
UD 2:
Introduce el peso de la UD (0-100): 20
Introduce la puntuación obtenida (0-100):40
UD 3:
Introduce el peso de la UD (0-100): 60
Introduce la puntuación obtenida (0-100):80
TOTAL UDs 
Nota final ponderada de las UDs (sobre 100): 70.0
```

Y esto es lo que tengo por ahora:

```
import java.util.*;

public class EvaluacionUd {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   
   Scanner leerTeclado = new Scanner(System.in);
   unidades(leerTeclado);
   double nota = unidades(leerTeclado);
   System.out.println("TOTAL UDs");
   System.out.println("Nota final ponderada de las UDs (sobre 100): " + nota);
   
   }
   
   public static double unidades(Scanner leerTeclado) {
      System.out.println("UNIDADES:");
      System.out.print("Introduce el número de unidades: ");
      int unidad = leerTeclado.nextInt();
      double nota = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i <= unidad; i++) {
         System.out.println("UD " + i + ":");
         System.out.print("Introduce el peso de la UD (0-100): ");
         int peso = leerTeclado.nextInt();
         System.out.print("Introduce la puntuación obtenida (0-100): ");
         int puntuacion = leerTeclado.nextInt();
         nota += puntuacion * peso / 100;
         return nota;
         
      }
   }
   
}
```

Gracias por los aportes.

Comment: `double nota += puntuacion * peso / 100;` con ello podes acumular la nota en cada iteracion pero recuerda declarar la variable nota fuera el for

Comment: @Dramaturgo, la formula me ha servido, gracias, pero ahora el problema es que cuando intento hacer el `return` de la  `nota` no me deja.

Comment: "No me deja" no es un error en programación. El problema que tienes es que has puesto el return dentro del for, con lo cual tu método no tiene un retorno constante puesto que si no entra al for, no habrá return. Mueve el return a debajo del for y listo... además no tiene sentido tenerlo dentro, puesto que hace que el bucle no funcione, saliéndose siempre a la primera iteración.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución, como me aconsejaron, era usar un acumulador y posteriormente usar el return fuera del bucle para devolver la nota.

```
import java.util.*;

public class EvaluacionUd {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   
   Scanner leerTeclado = new Scanner(System.in);   
   double nota = unidades(leerTeclado);
   System.out.println("TOTAL UDs");
   System.out.println("Nota final ponderada de las UDs (sobre 100): " + nota);
   
   }
   
   public static double unidades(Scanner leerTeclado) {
      System.out.println("UNIDADES:");
      System.out.print("Introduce el número de unidades: ");
      int unidad = leerTeclado.nextInt();
      double nota = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i <= unidad; i++) {
         System.out.println("UD " + i + ":");
         System.out.print("Introduce el peso de la UD (0-100): ");
         int peso = leerTeclado.nextInt();
         System.out.print("Introduce la puntuación obtenida (0-100): ");
         int puntuacion = leerTeclado.nextInt();
         nota += puntuacion * peso / 100;
         }
         return nota;
         
   }
}
```

Gracias por las respuestas.

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta? o es parte de tu pregunta

Comment: @Israel-ICM hola, pensaba que no hacía falta aclararlo ya que está publicado como respuesta. Al final con la ayuda de los comentarios solucioné mi problema y publiqué la respuesta.

Comment: No es necesario aclararlo, solo que siempre es bueno agregar un poco de explicación del como lo solucionaste, ya que cuando solo se agrega código no es muy comprensible sobre todo para los usuarios nuevos, y también porque muchos usuario (nuevos) erran al agregar código como respuesta cuando en realidad va en la pregunta. De todas formas seria mucho mejor si completas un poco tu respuesta para que este no sea de baja calidad. ;) un saludo.

Comment: @Israel-ICM Ok, hecho.